# Кусочек массива как аргумент функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть функция
`name(str1, str2, str3)`,
есть массив
`SUBJECTS[["info_1", "info_2", "info_3"], ["info1_1", "info1_2", "info1_3"] и так далее]`
И надо вызвать функцию, с аргуменатми из массива. Я пробовал

```py
print(SUBJECTS[0]) # Чтоб знать чо там в функцию идёт.
name(SUBJECTS[0])
```

И получал не то что мне нужно, а именно сообщение о том что не хватает еще двух аргументов.

```
['info_1', 'info_2', 'info_3']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", something line, in <module>
    name(SUBJECTS[0])
TypeError: name() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'str2' and 'str3'
```

Возможно я сделал что то не так в раковом плане, но я даже не предполагаю как по другому можно.

Comment: Да вам надо передавать не 1, а 3 аргумента для функции name()

Comment: Используй распаковку аргументов с помощью `*SUBJECTS[0]` [тут](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) есть  примеры как это делать.

Comment: Serhii Khortiuk, Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUBJECTS[0] это одна переменная (список, состоящий из трёх элементов).

Сделать можно так

```
print(*SUBJECTS[0])
```

Или так

```
print(SUBJECTS[0][0], SUBJECTS[0][1], (SUBJECTS[0][2]))
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне понравился вариант от [Serhii Khortiuk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/386887/serhii-khortiuk): ```Используй распаковку аргументов с помощью *SUBJECTS[0]```

Comment: Ээээм, первый вариант в моем ответе и есть распаковка...

Comment: Блин, затупил немного, слишком сильный акцент сделал на последнию строчку :D. Извеняюсь и приношу не просто спасибо, а огромное спасибо.

Во всяком случае он оставил ссылку на сайт с примерами)